# Can I store system output into a variable as this python script can?

Tags: c++

I am currently looking at  [this Stack Overflow question regarding a python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118397/storing-result-from-gdallocationinfo-as-variable-in-python).

I am working in C++. In their question, they are assigning a variable to the value of a system call's output, as so :

```
result = os.system('gdallocationinfo -valonly -wgs84 %s %s %s' % (raster, lon, lat))
```

Is this possible to do in C++? I must execute the system call and return is as a string. I am unable to find anything, besides sending the output to a file and then reading it. I have to run the command 1000's of times, so that method is much too slow. I am having trouble finding much information on this.

Comment: There's no standard C++ support for spawning subprocesses. What operating system(s) do you need to support? Each one will have its own library.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 currently.

Comment: Use `_popen` or redirection: `system("thing ... > output.txt")`.